# PHP use same Linux user to create and CHMOD a file

Tags: php

I'm trying to `CHMOD` a newly created file however you can only do this in Linux if you're the file owner. So even though `get_current_user()` is `exampled` in example the file is created for the user `root`.

```
<?php
$result = file_put_contents($dir.$file,$content);
$chmod = chmod($dir.$file,0646);
echo get_current_user();//user = exampled
echo posix_getpwuid(fileowner($dir.$file))['name'];//user = root
?>
```

How do I have PHP create and `CHMOD` a file as the same Linux user?

Comment: Shouldn't `$dir.$url_script` be `$dir.$file`?

Comment: @B.Fleming I change things to *not* copy code directly as is from the source code.

Comment: @John By who this file was created initially? by your app or internally in Linux environment?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco File is created by PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP it's possible to *attempt* to change Linux user ownership of a file using [chown()](https://www.php.net/chown):

```
$result1 = chown($dir.$file,posix_getpwuid(fileowner($dir.$url_script))['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like another solution you can use `shell_exec()` to execute command on server side.

```
<?php
    $link = $dir.$file;
    shell_exec("chmod 646 $link");
?>
```

This is allow you you to use same user `www-data` who created this file.